# How to get outgoing call start conversation time?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I want to log my calls in the app. I'm working with `Telephonymanager` and `onCallStateChanged` in broadcastreceiver.

So we have three states:

```
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE
```

When i start outgoing call, the `onCallStateChanged` with `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` is called. Then i wait for the answer. When a person takes the phone, the conversation starts, but `onCallStateChanged` is not triggered with any of these 3 states. How to get the exact time, when we start speaking?

Comment: There is not any event which is triggered when a person actually picks up the phone. Currently not possible with just these events.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless your app is the default phone app on the device.

If your app is a Phone app, and the user manually set it to be the default phone app, and your app also implements [`InCallService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService.html) to handle incoming call screen.

You'll get in your `InCallService` implementation an object of type [`Call`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.html) which contains such information (so you can switch the UI on screen when such event happens.

It is not possible to get the `Call` object if you're not the default Phone app IMHO.